# VBScript to login to a website and navigate to another page while maintaining the session

Tags: vbscript

I am new to VBScript (it took me a while to learn that VBA, VB.Net and VBScript are different!) and am struggling with a seemingly simple script.

I intend to access a URL and capture the http status code but I to need login first because it redirects me to the login page. I can login but I don't know how I should navigate to the page whose http status code I need.

How do I ensure that after logging in, the session is active for me to access a particular page?

Here's my code:

```
set httpObj = CreateObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")

httpObj.open "POST","http://sampleWebsite/login.asp",false
formValues = "user=username&pass=password"

httpObj.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpObj.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(formValues)
httpObj.send formValues
chkStatus = httpObj.status
respTxt=httpObj.responseText

If chkStatus = 200 Then
  If (InStr(respTxt,"<title>Sign In")) Then
    WScript.Echo "The login failed!"
    Else
    WScript.Echo "Login was successfull!"
  End If
End If
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

Just tried the URL in the same website after successfully logging in. Checked if the URL was redirecting to the login page or the home page. Checked this by logging the responseText in a text file and verifying it with the page source.

```
set httpObj = CreateObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")

httpObj.open "POST","http://sampleWebsite/login.asp",false
formValues = "user=user_name&pass=pass_word"

httpObj.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
httpObj.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(formValues)
httpObj.send formValues
chkStatus = httpObj.status
respTxt=httpObj.responseText

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strLogName =  "log.txt"
strLogPath = "C:\Users\useracc\Documents\Logs\" & strLogName ' Set log path here.
' Instantiate Logging
Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLogPath, 8, 2)

If chkStatus = 200 Then
    If (InStr(respTxt,"<font color=red><B>The user ID or password you have entered does not exist.")) Then
        WScript.Echo "The login failed!"
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Initialized    ####################"
        WriteLog respTxt
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Completed    ####################"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Login was successfull!"
       'WScript.Echo respTxt
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Initialized    ####################"
        WriteLog respTxt
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Completed    ####################"
   End If
End If

httpObj.open "GET","http://sampleWebsite/home.asp",false
httpObj.send
chkStatus = httpObj.status
respTxt=httpObj.responseText

If chkStatus = 200 Then
    If (InStr(respTxt,"Please enter a valid user name and password to continue.<br>")) Then
        WScript.Echo "Session is inactive!"
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Initialized    ####################"
        WriteLog respTxt
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Completed    ####################"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Session is active!"
        'WScript.Echo respTxt
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Initialized    ####################"
        WriteLog respTxt
        WriteLog "####################     Script Log Completed    ####################"
  End If
End If

Sub WriteLog(sEntry)
    'On Error Resume Next
    objLogFile.WriteLine(Now() & ": Log:      " & sEntry)
End Sub
```